# django does not reassign id number to model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I created a django model for applicants. i made it in such a way that the admin can delete an applicant's name from the model. But whenever an applicant's name is deleted the IDs remain the same, for exmaple if i delete an applicant with ID number 4 instead of the next applicant's number to become the new 4 it remains 5.

here is my code view code:

```
`def delete(request, id):
    applicant = Applicants.objects.get(id=id)
    applicant.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('applicants_list'))
```

html code:

```
<table border="1" >
    {% for x in myapplicants %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.fname }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.lname }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.p_course }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.total_grade }}</td>
            <td><button><a href="delete/{{ x.id }}" >Reject Application</a></button></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>`
```

Comment: Am assuming The id field on the model is an auto-increment one , The db keep the index of the last integer and whenever u add a new row it assigns +1.

Comment: This is normal behavior and shouldn't limit you. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans it is a problem because i am displaying the table on my HTML admin page, and it will look weird when the number starts with 4